# InnoSetup generates user desktop icon even with {commondesktop}

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut-file

I want to make an installer that will set desktop icons for all users. I use the following code:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

`commondesktop` is said to provide me with Public user desktop icon, but it creates one on my user desktop! Just as `userdesktop` does.
What is wrong here? I tried running it as administrator with the same result. Icon is truly on my desktop, I checked it via general properties of .lnk file.
Please let me know if some other piece of code is required.

Comment: Common Desktop (Public Desktop) icons are displayed on Every User Account - if you will log on to another account you will see this icon too (`c:\Users\Public\Desktop\ `). User Desktop icons are displayed only on The Very User Desktop (e.g. `c:\Users\ROBEN\Desktop\ `) that it was created for - if you will log on to another account you will NOT see this icon it the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the others were misinterpreting your question.  I am having the same problem and the cause of my issue is that I have the following in my .iss:

```
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
```

In the documentation you can see this:

> - = The "common" form of this constant is mapped to the "user" form if the logged-in user lacks administrative privileges, or if PrivilegesRequired is set to lowest

I believe that means even if you run the installer as an administrator the {commondesktop} will be mapped to the user desktop because of PrivilegesRequired.

Comment: I have `PrivilegesRequired=admin` and got the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

`{commondesktop}` is for all user.Here any user can see other user icon.`{userdesktop}`is use to place icon in desktop of user who is installing your application,So `{commondesktop}` will place icon in `{userdesktop}` too,But `{userdesktop}` will never place icon in `{commondesktop}`(anyuser can see this).